# Photoshop: Smart Objects Settings?

Tags: settings, photoshop, application-settings

Is there a setting for smart objects in Photoshop (CS4) that change how they scale when using their handles. For some reason holding SHIFT is no longer maintaining their proportional aspect ratio and I'm not sure what's wrong. Seems like I must have accidentally hot-key toggled some setting off. Any ideas?

Comment: you could try using http://photo.stackexchange.com/ - its stackexchange site about photos.

Comment: FTR, should not go to http://photo.stackexchange.com, which is about _photography_, not about photo imaging software in general. Smart objects and handles are definitely off the mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an odd kernel-type error that refused to clear itself until I completely shut down my computer.  If nothing else works, and you run across this issue, try shutting down.